# Why does the control button disable on lock screen and command center when playing Music?

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, remote-control, remotecommand

Why dos the control button disable on lock screen and command center when playing Music? I use MPRemoteCommandCenter to control the access via remote. Please help me，tx very much.

**Btw**

1. The app was not killed.
2. I add admob SDK as my app Interstitial AD.

[control button disable on command center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/be2DT.jpg)

[control button disable on lock screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JMmaK.jpg)

```
    if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] >= 7.1) {
    MPRemoteCommandCenter *commandCenter = [MPRemoteCommandCenter sharedCommandCenter];
    commandCenter.playCommand.enabled = YES;
    [commandCenter.playCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playAction:)];

    [commandCenter.pauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseAction:)];

    commandCenter.previousTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
    [commandCenter.previousTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(previousTrackAction:)];

    commandCenter.nextTrackCommand.enabled = YES;
    [commandCenter.nextTrackCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(nextTrackAction:)];

    commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand.enabled = YES;
    [commandCenter.togglePlayPauseCommand addTarget:self action:@selector(playOrPauseAction:)];
}
```